Struggling to build an ascending and alternating recursive function identifier in C
I am trying to build an algorithm by C programming that gets any positive integer and says if it's an ascending and alternating series of even and odd digits (9876 or 8765 from right to left) or not.

The getNumber function is supposed to ensure the integer is positive.
The isAscendingOrder function is supposed to check if the digits in the integer ascend - Returning 1 if they do or return 0 if not.
The isAlternateNumber function is supposed to check if the series alternates between even and odd numbers by recursion - Return 1 if it does (even, odd, even, odd,...,0) or return 0 if it doesn't.

My issue here is that I don't know how to build a recursion function that will detect if the integer is a series that alternates, or even how to start.
It would be very helpful if someone could guide me on how I should start or how to find the pattern.
Code:
#include <stdio.h>

int getNumber();
int isAscendingOrder(int num);
int isAlternateNumber(int num);

void main()
{
    //Note: Maybe using long long declaration!
    int num = getNumber();
    
    if (isAscendingOrder(num) && isAlternateNumber(num))
    {
        printf("Yes\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("No\n");
    }
}

int isAlternateNumber(int num)
{
    printf("Starting test with: %d\n", num);

    if (num <= 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return num / isAlternateNumber((num % 2) - 1);
}

int isAscendingOrder(int num)
{
    int ascendingNum = 0, editedNum = 0, alteraningNum, a, b;

    alteraningNum = num;
    editedNum = num;

    while (num > 0)
    {
        //Fix for 0
        if (num <= editedNum)
        {
            a = (num % 10);
            num /= 10;
            /*printf("a = %d\n", a);*/
        }

        if (num < editedNum)
        {
            b = (num % 10);
            editedNum = num;
            /*printf("b = %d\n", b);*/
        }
        
        if ((b < a) && (b != 0)) {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    isAlternateNumber(alteraningNum);

    return 1;
}

int getNumber(int validNum)
{
    do
    {
        printf("Please enter a positive integer: ");
        scanf_s("%d", &validNum);
    } while (validNum < 0);

    return validNum;
}

Note: I'm only allowed to use arithmetic operations, condition statements, loops and functions (including recursion).
I can't use structures, methods or anything else that I didn't mention here.

A sequence of digits that ascends when looked at from right to left descends when looked at from left to right.  Much the easiest way to deal with this is as a problem in string handling.  Read the input as a string.  Check that the string only contains digits.  Check that the string is not longer than 10 digits.  Check whether the digits are in descending order.  (Does 9630 count as valid?  What about 98543210?)  Check whether the digits are alternating odd and even.  (Does it matter whether the first digit is odd or even?)

If you're not allowed to use string operations, think about how to identify the Nth digit in a number and use that repeatedly.  Can you make an array of the digits in the number for further analysis?  If arrays can be used, then make an array of the digits and then analyze them as I outlined for a string.  Otherwise, just accept that the exercise is silly and use one function to determine the number of digits in the value, and another to get the Nth digit of the number — you can count from left or right as seems best to you (both can be made to work; just be consistent).

Minor note: void main() { ... } => int main(void) { ... }

Note: recursion here is not an efficient approach, yet a reasonable learning exercise.
Use %10 to isolate the least significant digit.

If isAscendingOrderfunction() is to take only 1 argument, it can test the order of the least 2 significant digits.
// For positive `x`.
bool isAscendingOrderfunction(int x) {
  int ones_place = x % 10;
  x /= 10;
  int tens_place = x % 10;
  return x == 0 //
      || (tens_place > ones_place && isAscendingOrderfunction(x));
}


Like-wise isAlternateNumber() can also compare the even/oddness of the 2 least significant digits.  A value is even if the remainder, after division by 2, is 0, otherwise the integer is odd.
// For all `x`.
bool isAlternateNumber(int x) {
  bool ones_place_is_even = (x % 2) == 0;
  x /= 10;
  bool tens_place_is_even = (x % 2) == 0;
  return x == 0 || //
      ((ones_place_is_even != tens_place_is_even) && isAlternateNumber(x));
}

Simplifications exsits, but something to get OP started.

I would rather use while loops with the C language, but you can certainly use recursion:
#include <stdbool.h>

bool isAlternateNumber(int num, bool odd)
{
    if (num == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    int parity = odd ? 1 : 0;
    return num % 2 == parity && isAlternateNumber(num / 10, !odd);
}

bool isAscendingOrder(int num, int minim)
{
    if (num == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return num % 10 >= minim && isAscendingOrder(num / 10, num % 10);
}

To build a recursive function, you need a stop condition: in both cases, we stop when we have no more figures to test, so when num == 0. At each recursive call, you remove the figure you just checked: num / 10. Because your functions must work for any figure in a number, you need information about how to deal with the current figure: shall it be odd or even, what is the minimum value ?
Note that recursion will stop on the first non-matching figure, because when the first operand of && evaluates to false, then the second operand is not evaluated.
Then you should call the functions like this:
bool altAndAsc = (isAlternateNumber(num, false) || isAlternateNumber(num, true)) && isAscendingOrder(num, 0);

